# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table db name xyz.core_url_rewrite' doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.8, database, install, composer

[image]

in local this error are display in my magento website plzz give me right answer

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because that is a necessary table for Magento I would imagine you have a incorrect install or you have setup your local XML without a prefix for your tables.

The other option is that you simply dropped that table.